# How to fix: loadValuesAsynchronously was deprecated in iOS 16.0

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I keep getting a warning that doesn't break my code but I would like to resolve the issue.

```
asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var error: NSError?
        let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)
```

The errors:

> 'loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys:completionHandler:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: Use load(_:) instead.  For non-deprecated properties that do not have an AVAsyncProperty equivalent, continue to query these properties synchronously

> 'statusOfValue(forKey:error:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: Use status(of:) instead

Tried to rename it but I don't know how.

Comment: What is the type of `asset`?

Comment: The error clearly states to use `load` instead of `loadValuesAsynchronously`. Show your attempt to use the new method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is this:

```
asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    var error: NSError?
    let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)
```

As the warning states, `loadValuesAsynchronously` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading/1387321-loadvaluesasynchronously) and suggests using `load(_:)`. Notice that it accepts an [AVAsyncProperty](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasyncproperty) as an argument.

So, if we revise the code snippet above, we get (for example):

```
let isPlayable = try await asset.load(.isPlayable)
```

**You can also pass in multiple properties**.